# Master-Detail Limitations

Tags: master-detail

We are evaluating the SFSC as an application development platform and have come up with this problem.

We need to establish how to overcome the Master-Detail limitations of 2 Detail objects per 1 Master object and the sub-level limitation of 3.

The following relationship diagram illustrates what we are trying to achieve.

[image: SFSC Master-Detail Relationships]

Has anyone found a way to overcome these limitations and if so be prepared to share their solution to this problem.

Comment: What is SFSC?....Is it SF Service Console?

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at. Each sub level 2 is a detail of account. Each sub level 1 is a detail of top level. Not sure why you need multiple MD on any of those as illustrated unless a sub-level item needs related to an item at the same level. The limit of 2 is an object cannot be a detail in a MD to more that two different masters. Masters can have a lot of MD detail records (children records)

Comment: Eric ... sorry we were looking at it the wrong way around. The Detail has a limit and not the Master. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Not wasting my time at all if asking the question got you to look at it differently and subsequently resolved your issue. Should I post the comment as an answer

Comment: Done............

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking at it backwards.

- Each sub level 2 is a detail of account.
- Each sub level 1 is a detail of top level.

Not sure why you need multiple MD on any of those as illustrated unless a sub-level item needs related to an item at the same level.

**The limit of 2 is an object cannot be a detail in a MD to more that two different masters. Masters can have a lot of MD detail records (children records)**